# python reading file with different informations according to line

Tags: python, input, readlines

I have a strange file:

```
515   30.00398       30.00153
1  4
A B A
A B B
A B C
A B D
2  4
A C A
A C B
A C C
A C D
```

This has been creating according to "fortran logic" (unfortunately).
I have to read it in python.
For me it is difficult to move to python logic. Indeed I have to read the first line and to store it in some variables. The 2nd and 7th lines give me information about other variables which value are related to the "letters".
I try to make myself clear.

I have variable called "cells". Each cell has number, in this case "1" and "2". Each cell has 4*3 elemenets. In this example cell "1" has:

```
A B A
A B B
A B C
A B D
```

how can I read all the file.

I have learnt to use:

```
for line in Lines:
    count += 1
    print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
```

This seems to work for files where all lines have the same type of element. What about my file.
How can read it properly? Some suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help

Comment: 1, 4 means 1st cell and there are 4 rows, right? And there is always 3 column? always? And what is your desired output?

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: what are the numbers on the first line?

Comment: if the separator is unknown number of spaces, you can do vars = [v for v in line.split(' ') if v is not ''] and get all the "things" in a line separated by an unknown number of spaces.

Comment: @Yuri, sorry, I don't think that is good advice – the canonical way to split at arbitrary whitespace is `.split()` without any argument, which gives the same result as your code. Also, `!=` is preferable over `is not`.

Comment: yes. 1 means first cells and 4 means the number of rows related to all the cells. As you can see also the second cells has 4 rows. I will always have 3 columns. I would like to store A,B,C... values for each cells. My idea is to have a list of object cell[i] where each object has the values A,B,C and so on. I hope to have made myself more clear than before.

Comment: @fsimonjetz you're right, vars = [v for v in line.split() if v != ''] is better and do the same.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# assuming that your file.txt is like

# 515   30.00398       30.00153
# 1  5
# A B A
# A B B
# A B C
# A B D
# P Q R
# 2  4
# A C A
# A C B
# A C C
# A C D

cells = [] # cell0, cell 1, cell2 etc

with open('file.txt') as f:
    # discarding 515   30.00398       30.00153
    next(f)
    
    cell_line = f.readline()
    while(cell_line != ''):
        cell_no, number_of_rows = map(int, cell_line.split())
        cell = [[0,0,0] for i in range(number_of_rows)]

        for i in range(number_of_rows):
            cell[i][0], cell[i][1], cell[i][2] = f.readline().split()
        cells.append(cell)

        cell_line = f.readline()
    
print(cells)

# [[['A', 'B', 'A'],
#   ['A', 'B', 'B'],
#   ['A', 'B', 'C'],
#   ['A', 'B', 'D'],
#   ['P', 'Q', 'R']], ---> cell 0
#  [['A', 'C', 'A'], ['A', 'C', 'B'], ['A', 'C', 'C'], ['A', 'C', 'D']]] ---> cell 1
```

Comment: I like this approach – I think I'd change the middle part of the while loop to sth like `cells.append([f.readline().split() for _ in range(number_of_rows)])` instead of building the `cell` matrix first and filling it via indexing afterwards, but I guess it's a matter of personal preference!

Comment: Ya, that is also possible

Comment: Due to the fact that in my "real file" I have 15 columns, is there any way to substitute cell = [[0,0,0] for i in range(number_of_rows)] with something more compact? I was thinking about an array with numpy. What do you think?

Comment: Then try something like `np.empty((15, number_of_rows), dtype=str)`

Comment: I have done:
cell = np.empty((number_of_rows,15), dtype=str) //
for i in range(number_of_rows):
cell[i][:] = f.readline().split(). //It seems not working. I does not recognize the split am array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using readLine
#readLine() will read you line by line
#readLines() will read entire file in a list

```
with open('fortan_file.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readLines()
    for count, line in enumerate(Lines):
      print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
```

if you are aware of lines in between

```
lines.seek(line_numer)
```

#seek will redirect the pointer to given line
Adding a if condition would do the work!

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know your desired output, I'm assuming a **3x4 matrix** could be a good data structure for your cell.

Maybe building a dictionary with ***cell_number: matrix*** pairs could be a good implementation:

```
data = open("file.txt").readlines()[1:] # get a list of all lines except header

cells = {f"cell_{i+1}": data[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(data), 4)}
```

This seems complicated as it's very comprehensive but it's kind of intuitive actually.

Mind you, this is a specific solution to a specific problem, so make sure what your file has the same structure as in your post.